# HTTP Request in Swift with POST method for a large amount of data

Tags: swift, networking, data-structures

I have a data structure in which a very large amount of images (~500) are "recorded" from the screen and sent to a server for processing. This data structure has caused an abundance of memory issues within my app.

**My current solution is to use CoreData for the storage and retrieval of each structure, but how would I be able to send this structure to the server without loading the images into memory?**

I am currently using URLSession data tasks for POSTing, which works for structures with a small number of images since I load them into memory for JSON encoding. Each frame also needs to have high resolution. The "recording" is done using snapshot() from ARSCNView since the renders need to be in each frame as well.

Here is the code I use for POST requests:

```
/*
 Configures POST request for the server
 Returns a URLRequest configured to be POSTed containing a JSON encoded DISCRequest object
 */
private func generatePostRequest(from images: [Data], dataList: [[Int]])->URLRequest{
    var request=URLRequest(url: url)
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = try? JSONEncoder().encode(DISCRequest(images: images, dataList: dataList))
    return request
}
/*
 Performs a POST request to the server.
 Success: passes results to the completion handler
 Fail: prints error, nothing returned
 Param:
 -imgs: array of images that make up input video
 -dataList: screen locations of each faceAnchor index in order
 -sender: view controller to handle possible error handling for reference
 -completion: closure for the call, manages returned results
 */
func postToServer(imgs: [Data], dataList: [[Int]], _ sender: ViewController, completion: @escaping([UIImage])->Void){
    let request=generatePostRequest(from: imgs, dataList: dataList)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if  error != nil  {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //sender.videoError(title: "Unable to process video", message: "Unable to connect to Network", presentVideo: false)
            }
            return
        }
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                    (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //sender.videoError(title: "Unable to process video", message: "Error with the response, unexpected status code: \((response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode)", presentVideo: false)
            }
            return
          }
        guard let data=data else{
            print("No data in response.")
            return
        }
        if let decoded=try? JSONDecoder().decode(DISCRequest.self, from: data){
            completion(decoded.images.map({ i in
                UIImage(data: i)!
            }))
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Where DISCRequest is just an in-memory structure that houses the images/other data. The CoreData equivalent (SaveData) structure has the same properties as DISCRequest.

Comment: Please share the relevant code and show what you have tried so far so that people can make suggestions.

Comment: You might want to use multiformpart data to upload what I understand is heavy objects. What's the count of `request.httpBody` in your case? Else, you also might want to do it by batch of 5, 10 or n (you decide after your tests), because on the server side it also might be heavy for it...